# Boost python on mac os x lion with custom python

Tags: c++, python, xcode, macos, boost-python

I'm trying to get boost python to work with a custom python library. I have a python source and build boost.python using :

`./bootstrap.sh --with-python-root=../Python-2.7.2 --with-libraries=python`

then `./b2`

but when I try to use boost.python in my application, I get

`Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)`

When I call `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nprint sys.version");`, I get 2.7.2, as I expect (and the version of python I build boost.python with; not the system version.)

Is there something I'm missing?

When I check what libraries the dylib is linked with, I get this:

```
libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.1)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)`
```

In my Xcode target, I include the python from the --with-python-root argument folder and the content of boost/stage/lib,

[image: Link Libraries]

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded boost python and compiled it against my custom python installed using Mac Ports and it seems to be working just fine.

My steps...

```
$ /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov 17 2011, 00:52:26)    
$ sudo ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python --with-python-root=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
$ ./b2
$ cd /Users/YourName/Downloads/boost_1_48_0/libs/python/example/tutorial
$ ../../../../bjam 
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1577 targets...
...updating 12 targets...
common.mkdir bin
common.mkdir bin/darwin-4.2.1
common.mkdir bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug
darwin.compile.c++ bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello.o
darwin.link.dll bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello_ext.so
common.copy libboost_python.dylib
common.copy hello_ext.so
common.mkdir bin/hello.test
common.mkdir bin/hello.test/darwin-4.2.1
common.mkdir bin/hello.test/darwin-4.2.1/debug
capture-output bin/hello.test/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello
**passed** bin/hello.test/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello.test
...updated 12 targets...
$ ls
Jamroot         hello.cpp       hello_ext.so
bin         hello.py        libboost_python.dylib
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov 17 2011, 00:52:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hello_ext
>>> hello_ext.greet()
'hello, world'
>>>
```

Additionally if you don't need be able to build everything yourself you can utilize mac ports to help you out.  I haven't tried it, but it looked like boost.python was available, though version 1.47 instead of 1.48.

```
$ port info boost
boost @1.47.0, Revision 2 (devel)
Variants:             debug, no_single, no_static, openmpi, python24, python25, python26, python27, python31, python32, regex_match_extra,
                      universal

Description:          Boost provides free portable peer-reviewed C++ libraries. The emphasis is on portable libraries which work well with
                      the C++ Standard Library.
Homepage:             http://www.boost.org

Library Dependencies: zlib, expat, bzip2, icu
Platforms:            darwin
License:              Boost-1.0
Maintainers:          adfernandes@macports.org
```

Actually, in order to solve this we can take a look at our environment and compare if you still have problems :).

$ echo $press-TAB

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're linking boost python against the wrong version of python (2.7.0), and your application against the right version of python (2.7.2) - `PyRun_SimpleString` has nothing to do with boost python, but is a direct call into the Python API from your test app.

I use a `project-config.jam` file (in the boost build directory) to configure which python boost-python should be built with, including this line (for linking against my simple 2.7 installation):

```
using python : 2.7 : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/ ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My project-config.jam contains `using python : 2.7 : ../Python-2.7.2/ ;`, but otool still lists the `/System/Library/Framework` entry.

Comment: @sharvey I suppose you've tried a clean build, specifying absolute path, and `using python : 2.7.2 : ...` and all that?

Comment: I can't put `2.7.2`, it gives me a warning saying : `Warning: "using python" expects a two part (major, minor) version number; got 2.7.2 instead`. Using absolute path doesn't change anything. Cleaning both in Xcode and `./b2 --clean` still doesn't fix the issue...

Comment: Hmmmmm. Well it's definitely that boost python is linking against the wrong version. You don't have a user-config.jam file somewhere overriding your version do you? Perhaps it's worth moving aside the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` python that boost python is picking up while you build and install it.

Answer (score 0):

### First check

It may be a mismatch between the dylib that are linked and the include really used. One simple check is to pass the option `--debug-configuration` to bjam and to check the include and link paths:

```
./b2 -q --prefix=your_install_dir YOU_OTHER_OPTIONS --debug-configuration install
```

should yield these lines in the beginning:

```
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified version: "2.7"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified cmd-or-prefix: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python"...
notice: [python-cfg] running command '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config" "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib"
notice: [python-cfg] framework directory is "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework"
```

you should see that interpreter, include and binaries match (`interpreter command`, `include path` and `library path` respectively).

If there is a mismatch, check the `python-config` file in `usr/bin`: it should point to the python.org installation path. If not, the installer missed it and it should be fixed.

### Second check

It may be that the library that is linked against is not properly set in `/usr/lib`. By a simple `ls -al /usr/lib/*python*`, you should see a `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib` that points to your python.org installation. If not, the python.org installer missed it and it should be fixed.

Sorry for being a bit vague. I had this issue 1 year ago and fixed it by hand by doing many thing until it worked...